# How to assign the value of one attribute of one array of object to the similarly named attribute of another array of object? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code

I have 2 arrays of objects - arr1 and arr2

```
  var arr1 = [{
        id: 1,
        city: 'London',
        'checked': false
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        city: 'NYC',
        'checked': false
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        city: 'Paris',
        'checked': false
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        city: 'Madrid',
        'checked': false
        }];


 var arr2 = [{
        id: 1,
        city: 'Madrid',
        'checked': true
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        city: 'Paris',
        'checked': false
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        city: 'NYC',
        'checked': true
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        city: 'London',
        'checked': false
        }];
```

Using these 2 array of objects, I want to create a arr3 variable/array of objects (arr3 will retain the order of arr1 - first London, then NYC, third Paris and last Madrid. I only want to get the checked of arr2 objects and put that field (checked attribute) value in arr1 and create arr3. The order should not be changed, just the checked of arr1 will get its value from checked of arr2.

```
  var arr3 = [{
        id: 1,
        city: 'London',
        'checked': false
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        city: 'NYC',
        'checked': true
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        city: 'Paris',
        'checked': false
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        city: 'Madrid',
        'checked': true
        }];
```

I also have an option of not using arr3, then I can directly do the changes in arr1. This is also another way. Any technique will work for me.

Updated - the order of id attribute in arr3 should be same as it is in arr1

Answer (score 4):

## Explained

With this approach, it uses more of a modern approach, makign use of functions such as [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), plus personally I find that this implementation is pretty much as simplistic as it could possibly be.

If you're not familiar with the 'arrow function' syntax, you can find plenty of documentation online, such as [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). But as you can see, the beauty of this approach is that it's clean, concise and simple.

This implementation is somewhat similar to the answer provided by @holydragon, however when you use a `forEach` function, you're allowing for side effects to occur, at least with this implementation, by making use of `map`, this should reduce the chances of side effects within your code.

Furthermore, I've also made use of the [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) just to further reduce the chance(s) of side effects in this snippet.

#### Update

I've implemented my solution using the `destructuring assignment` not because it's 'modern' or anything silly like that. It's because without creating a copy of the object(s), when modifying the `checked` property for the objects in `arr3`, the `checked` properties in the objects found within `arr1` would also get updated.

This is an example of a side effect, if you'd like to delve more into functional programming, related concepts and specifically functional programming with JavaScript, I strongly recommend that you read some of [Eric's](https://medium.com/@_ericelliott) content. Personally I'm a fan of the content that Eric publishes, and when I was trying to apply functional programming concepts to JavaScript, I found his content useful.

```js
var arr1 = [{id:1,city:"London",checked:!1},{id:2,city:"NYC",checked:!1},{id:3,city:"Paris",checked:!1},{id:4,city:"Madrid",checked:!1}];
var arr2 = [{id:1,city:"Madrid",checked:!0},{id:2,city:"Paris",checked:!1},{id:3,city:"NYC",checked:!0},{id:4,city:"London",checked:!1}];


var arr3 = arr1.map(({...o}) => {
  o.checked = arr2.find(x => x.city === o.city).checked;
  return o;
});
console.log(arr3);

// If you want a one line solution... 
var arr4 = arr1.map(({...o}) => Object.assign(o, {checked : arr2.find(x => x.city === o.city).checked}));
console.log(arr4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). With `arr1.map(...)` you maintain the order of array one and with the `arr2.find(...)` you will get the `checked` property value in `arr2`.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1,city: 'London','checked': false},{id: 2,city: 'NYC','checked': false},{id: 3,city: 'Paris','checked': false},{id: 4,city: 'Madrid','checked': false}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1,city: 'Madrid','checked': true},{id: 2,city: 'Paris','checked': false},{id: 3,city: 'NYC','checked': true},{id: 4,city: 'London','checked': false}];
const arr3 = arr1.map(c1 => ({
  id: c1.id,
  city: c1.city,
  checked: arr2.find(c2 => c1.city === c2.city).checked
}));

console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and merge same cities.

```js
var array1 = [{ city: 'London', checked: false }, { city: 'NYC', checked: false }, { city: 'Paris', checked: false }, { city: 'Madrid', checked: false }],
    array2 = [{ city: 'Madrid', checked: true }, { city: 'Paris', checked: false }, { city: 'NYC', checked: true }, { city: 'London', checked: false }],
    result = Array.from([...array1, ...array2]
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.city, o), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If needed, you could assign only wanted property to the map.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, city: 'London', checked: false }, { id: 2, city: 'NYC', checked: false }, { id: 3, city: 'Paris', checked: false }, { id: 4, city: 'Madrid', checked: false }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, city: 'Madrid', checked: true }, { id: 2, city: 'Paris', checked: false }, { id: 3, city: 'NYC', checked: true }, { id: 4, city: 'London', checked: false }],
    result = Array.from([...array1, ...array2]
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(
            o.city,
            Object.assign(m.get(o.city) || o, { checked: o.checked })
        ), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like this answer as it's different from the majority of other answers, including my own, I wouldn't have thought of this. My only question is, would this be better/worse for performance than say the solution that I've provided? :)

Comment: I have modified the question, it now has an id attribute. Can you kindly check the modified question

Answer (score 1):

**(UPDATED) STEPS:**

1. Iterate through `arr1`.
2. Get the object in `arr2` where the city property matched from both arrays.
3. Update the `checked` property in `arr1` according to the matched object from `arr2`.

```js
var arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    city: 'London',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'NYC',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    city: 'Paris',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    city: 'Madrid',
    'checked': false
  }
];


var arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    city: 'Madrid',
    'checked': true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'Paris',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    city: 'NYC',
    'checked': true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    city: 'London',
    'checked': false
  }
];

arr1.forEach(a1 => {
  a1.checked = arr2.filter(a2 => a2.city === a1.city)[0].checked
})
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Iterate through first array

2.Iterate through second array

3.when city of arr1 == city of arr 2

4. save checked of arr2 in arr1

```js
var arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    city: 'London',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'NYC',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    city: 'Paris',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    city: 'Madrid',
    checked: false
  }
];


var arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    city: 'Madrid',
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'Paris',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    city: 'NYC',
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    city: 'London',
    checked: false
  }
];

arr1.forEach(function(entry1) {
  arr2.forEach(function(entry2) {
    if (entry1.city == entry2.city) {
      entry1.checked = entry2.checked;
    }

  })
});
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: What will happen if I have an id attribute in ascending order, from 1 to 4 in both arr1 and arr2. Suppose in arr1, London has id 1 while in arr2 Madrid has Id 1. In arr3 I want to retain the order of id as in arr1

Comment: @Scooby my example modifies the array 1 according to the checked of array 2

Comment: I have modified the question, have included another field called id, kindly check

Comment: @Scooby ass you said that using array 3 is an option so id of arr1 will remain same. check updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with key value pair as city name and checked value from array 2.

```
var array2Obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    array2Obj[arr2[i].city] = arr2[i].checked;
}
```

Now loop array 1 and assign the city value of the object (which is the checked value of array 2) to array 1 checked value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i].checked = array2Obj[arr1[i].city];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and `forEach`

```js
var arr1 = [{
    city: 'London',
    'checked': false,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    city: 'NYC',
    'checked': false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    city: 'Paris',
    'checked': false,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    city: 'Madrid',
    'checked': false,
    id: 4
  }
];


var arr2 = [{
    city: 'Madrid',
    'checked': true
  },
  {
    city: 'Paris',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    city: 'NYC',
    'checked': true
  },
  {
    city: 'London',
    'checked': false
  }
];
var arr3 = arr1.map(e => {
  arr2.forEach(x => x.city == e.city ? e.checked = x.checked : false)
  return e;
})
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: This ternary  operator is useless and confusing.